# Worksheet Looping User-Defined Function Malfunction

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, user-defined-functions

I'm programming some VBA code in Excel on a workbook which contains multiple tabs, most of which contain a table. I'm creating a user-defined function to count all instances of a given input combination (two inputs) within a single column on each worksheet. I realize there may be a non-vba workaround, but I'd like to keep this workbook to as little manual action as necessary when updates are made. Currently it doesn't contain many cells, but it may moving forward.

Ex: Given "Quality" and "Due Immediately" I'd like to count how many instances of this combination exist as "Quality: Due Immediately" within a given column of each worksheet's Table. Then, the total should be output as an integer on the initial worksheet (which is a summary page) where the function is called in a specific cell.

I've looked around for help on a few things, but I keep getting a "#VALUE" error on my function and I currently can't figure it out. I am still newer to VBA, so if I've done something stupid please give me some explanation. I'd appreciate it!

Here is my module:

```
Function StatusCounterByDepartment(Department As String, Status As String)
    Dim Counter As Integer: Counter = 0

    For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Activate
        For j = 2 To ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Rows.Count
            If (ActiveSheet.Range("H" & j).Value = Department & ": " & Status) Then
                Counter = Counter + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    StatusCounterByDepartment = Counter
End Function
```

My thought process was to cycle through the given column up until the end of the column's length, evaluate if it fit my criteria, add 1 to my counter for every instance in the active worksheet, and then cycle through the rest of my worksheets until I get a final count. Then, report that final count as the return value of my function.

Thanks for any help that can be provided!

Comment: please post a sample of your data as well

Comment: why not use countif()?

Comment: I will try to post a sample set later today. I realize that I could use "COUNTIFS()" as a solution to my problem, but should there ever be a workbook change I will have to go back in and manually adjust each formula, which I'd rather not do. I'm trying to make the worksheet as dummy proof as possible by allowing for additions and edits to the worksheet as much as possible without editing any formulas.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, I also wanted to use the opportunity to expand on my VBA knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not robust at all but I am just fixing the initial things. You might want to add proper error handling to deal with table not being present as an example of additional things to do.

```
Public Sub count()

MsgBox StatusCounterByDepartment("Quality", "Due Immediately")

End Sub

Public Function StatusCounterByDepartment(ByVal Department As String, ByVal Status As String) As Long
    Dim Counter As Long
    Counter = 0

    For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.count

       With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)

           On Error Resume Next

           For j = 2 To (1 + .ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.count)

               If (.Range("H" & j).Value = Department & ": " & Status) Then
                   Counter = Counter + 1
               End If

           Next j

           On Error GoTo 0

        End With

    Next i

    StatusCounterByDepartment = Counter
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a few more follow-up questions:

What is the purpose of including the top function with a MsgBox output? I'd like for the result of the function to simply return the number in the cell where the function was called so it can be updated automatically as new data is input.

Do I not need to declare certain worksheets, etc. as "Active"? I see that you go straight to using them versus declaring them active.

I do like your simplification of the (1+ ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.count) I find that far more elegant. In addition the "With" seems to help.

Comment: You don’t need the top sub. It was for demo purposes. You can use directly as Udf the function. Generally, you do not need to say active; it is safer to fully qualify the sheet you expect to be working in by it’s name.

Comment: The With statement means you don’t need the activate. It is more efficient as you can work with the required sheet without the overhead of activating it.

Comment: I put in your adjustments finally and it solved my issue. I'm not sure where my UDF was getting stuck, but I'm finally getting the numbers that I should be. Thanks for your help and your explanations!